# dynamically display images in a grid in html

Tags: html, image, gridview

The setup is as follows:

I have 25 folders, with each folder having some images. The number and filenames of images in each folder is decided after I run a C++ code. I want to display the images in these 25 folders in a 5x5 grid format **in an html file** with the size of each grid entry depending upon the number of images in the folder corresponding to that grid entry. I need to write an html script for it.

Since I have absolutely no experience in writing html scripts, I looked at some of the other posts in stackoverflow and elsewhere, but I could not find help on dynamically looking up folders and then displaying the images they contain. I would really appreciate if someone could help me on that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An HTML, script?  You mean a script from a scripting protocol that outputs HTML, correct?

It all depends on how ornate you want to go with the rendered HTML, do you just want these in an old fashioned, and ill suited table, or would a DIV based presentation with better stylability be better?

Comment: Hi Rob-not a robber(:P), an old fashioned way would work just fine as long as all the images are visible.

Answer (score 1):

As Zeychin says, you could use PHP to nicely and efficiently output HTML based on the query you make to those directories you've setup.

Look into PHP's $_SERVER and from that you should be able to query anything on the server form the root name to the contents of folders.  Deal with the data it returns to you and through looping you can easily output a tabular format which would roughly resemble the following

```
<table><!-- "Starts" table-->
<tr><!-- "Starts" row 1-->
<td><!-- "Starts" cell 1-->
</td><!-- "ends" cell 1-->
<td><!-- "Starts" cell 2-->
</td><!-- "ends" cell 2-->
<td><!-- "Starts" cell 3-->
</td><!-- "ends" cell 3-->
<td><!-- "Starts" cell 4-->
</td><!-- "ends" cell 4-->
<td><!-- "Starts" cell 5-->
</td><!-- "ends" cell 5-->
</tr><!-- "ends" row 1-->

... do this 4 more times ...

</table> <!-- "end" table-->
```

Comment: Hi Rob, could you send me a link to someplace that I can look into for more details on php scripts, with specific focus on my question. I would be really thankful.

Comment: Vinayak, provided your programming has dealt with all of the image processing and directory creation on the server, reference the PHP.net documentation.  For a C++ programmer, the uptake time to understand PHP should not be that long  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Also, do you have a working knowledge of HTML?  To facilitate your desired output, brush up on overall document structure http://www.webstandards.org/learn/reference/templates/, tables  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp, and the IMG tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp.  Get into DIV based layout and CSS to really jazz it up

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a server-side script best implemented in PHP/JSP, et cetera.
I'm rusty with my server-side stuff, so I'll leave this to those who are more familiar with the server-side material.